# How to pull to refresh without tableView?

Tags: ios, swift, pull-to-refresh

I have next controller:

```
final class CategoryBreakdownViewController: UIViewController {
  
    private let scrollView = UIScrollView(alwaysBounceVertical: true)
    var refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
```

Where in `viewDidLoad` I'm trying to implement pull to refresh without `tableView`:

```
 private func setupRefreshControl() {    
        scrollView.alwaysBounceVertical = true
        scrollView.bounces  = true
        refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(updateView), for: .valueChanged)
        self.scrollView.addSubview(refreshControl)
    }
    
    @objc func updateView() {
        SyncScheduler.syncImmediately(
            success: {
                self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
            },
            failure: { [weak self] errorMessage in
                self?.present(message: errorMessage, style: .error)
                self?.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
            }
        )
    }
```

But in my case this solution doesn't worked, how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be anything wrong with your approach.

Here is a complete example -- it adds a "full view" scrollView, with a 200-pt tall red subview (so we can see the effect).

When you drag down, you should see the `UIRefreshControl` "spinner" appear. Drag down far enough, and it will call the `updateView()` func. Since we don't have your `SyncScheduler` code, I added a 2-second async delay to simulate the process:

```
final class CategoryBreakdownViewController: UIViewController {
    
    private let scrollView = UIScrollView()
    var refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        scrollView.backgroundColor = .systemTeal
        scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        let testView = UIView()
        testView.backgroundColor = .red
        testView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        scrollView.addSubview(testView)
        view.addSubview(scrollView)
    
        let contentGuide = scrollView.contentLayoutGuide
        let frameGuide = scrollView.frameLayoutGuide
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor),
            scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor),
            scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
            scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor),
            
            testView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentGuide.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            testView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            testView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            testView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -20.0),

            testView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: frameGuide.widthAnchor, constant: -40.0),
            testView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200.0),
        ])

        setupRefreshControl()
    }
    
    private func setupRefreshControl() {
        scrollView.alwaysBounceVertical = true
        scrollView.bounces = true
        refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(updateView), for: .valueChanged)
        self.scrollView.addSubview(refreshControl)
    }
    
    @objc func updateView() {

        // simulate a background process that takes 2 seconds
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2.0, execute: {
            self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
        })
        
//      SyncScheduler.syncImmediately(
//          success: {
//              self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
//          },
//          failure: { [weak self] errorMessage in
//              self?.present(message: errorMessage, style: .error)
//              self?.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
//          }
//      )
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So you are missing two line of code:

```
self.scrollView.scrollEnabled = true
self.scrollView.alwaysBounceVertical = true
```

`var alwaysBounceVertical: Bool` // default NO. if YES and bounces is YES, even if content is smaller than bounds, allow drag vertically.

Please try this. Thanks

Comment: I'm trying to implement pull to refresh without `tableView`, that's why I bind to `scrollview`.

Comment: Please check my answer once again for making alwaysBounceVertical = true